# What's the difference between using IWICFormatConverter or WICConvertBitmapSource

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d, wic

I'm getting the bitmap pixeldata out of my ID2D1RenderTarget (it's a WICBitmapRenderTarget), but sometimes I want it to be in 8bpp grey. So I'm using WICConvertBitmapSource function because it looks simpler. But I would like to know if IWICFormatConverter interface would make any difference. Documentation shows no relation at all between them.

Thanks

Comment: WICConvertBitmapSource() is a convenience function, helps you avoid having to write a bunch of COM code and getting it wrong.  So the difference is that the function is just easier to use.